# How to find the value of $P(x)$ when $x=-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Q$)$ If $P(x)$ is a polynomial such that it satisfies the following conditions:$P(1)=2 , P(2)=3 , P(3)=5, P(4)=6, P(5)=8, P(6)=9, P(7)=10, P(8)=12, P(9)=14, P(10)=16, P(11)=19$ , then find the value of $P(-1)$ .

Given: $P(x)=ax^{10}+bx^{9}+cx^{8}+dx^{7}+ex^{6}+fx^{5}+gx^{4}+hx^{3}+ix^{2}+jx+k$

Ans$)$ **My approach**:

Let's start with an example.

If the question was like find $P(5)$ where $P(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ and $P(x)$ satisfies the conditions: $P(1)=2, P(2)=3, P(3)=5$ then it would become very easy to find the value of $P(5)$.

$P(1)=2$

$\implies a+b+c=2$ .....$(i)$

$P(2)=3$

$\implies 4a+2b+c=3$ .....$(ii)$

$P(3)=5$

$\implies 9a+3b+c=5$ .....$(iii)$

Now after solving the equations $(i),(ii),(iii)$ we will get the values of $a,b,c$ .

{$a,b,c$}={$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{-1}{2}, 2$}

Therefore, $P(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}+2$

Therefore, $P(5)=12$ .

Again, let's take an another example:

If the question was like find the value of $P(5)$ where $P(x)=ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d$ and $P(x)$ satisfies the following conditions: $P(1)=2, P(2)=3, P(3)=5, P(4)=6$ then also it would become very easy to find the value of $P(5)$ .

$P(1)=2$

$\implies a+b+c+d=2$ .....$(i)$

$P(2)=3$

$\implies 8a+4b+2c+d=3$ .....$(ii)$

$P(3)=5$

$\implies 27a+9b+3c+d=5$ .....$(iii)$

$P(4)=6$

$\implies 64a+16b+4c+d=6$ .....$(iv)$

Now after solving the equations $(i),(ii),(iii),(iv)$ we will get the values of $a,b,c,d$ .

{$a,b,c,d$}={$\frac{-1}{3},\frac{5}{2},\frac{-25}{6},4$}

Therefore, $P(x)=\frac{-x^{3}}{3}+\frac{5x^{2}}{2}-\frac{25x}{6}+4$

Therefore, $P(5)=4$

**My doubt:**

It will become a very hectic process for a person to find out the values of {$a,b,c,...,k$} in my question with the help of this process. This process is fine only for quadratic and cubic polynomials. But for a polynomial of degree $10$ it will be very much difficult and a hectic process to find out the value of $P(-1)$ by finding out $P(x)$ that is by finding the values of {$a,b,c,...,k$}.

**I want a shortcut process for this types of questions. Please help me out with this question of Polynomial.**

Comment: This question is not from any book. I only discovered this question and I finally want a shortcut process.

Comment: This is what you are seeking : [Lagrange polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Comment: Hi , look for Newton's Forward Difference method

Comment: There are **many** ways to accomplish [polynomial interpolation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polynomial_interpolation), including methods mentioned here in the comments due to Lagrange and Newton, but also Vandermonde, Gauss, Sterling, Bessel. The fundamental result is that, in general, we need a polynomial of degree $n$ to fit $n+1$ points.

Comment: I assume this means that you want a polynomial of minimal degree.

Comment: No. @alex.peter I want a shortcut process for finding the values of {$a,b,c,...,k$}

Comment: @DebSankarRoy Unless you restrict yourself to a polynomial with the same degree as the number of values you have, there is an infinite number of different polynomials of larger degree that would fit all the values.

Comment: I have edited my question. Now I want the value of $P(-1)$ instead of $P(15)$ because finding the value of $P(15)$ will  be a very lenghty process. Because then we have to calculate $(15)^{10}, (15)^{9}$,... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Direct approach** addressing the approach discussed in the question:

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $k$, with yet unknown coefficients $a_0, \ldots, a_k$ (which are the $a, b, c,\ldots$ in your question), so the polynomial looks like this $$P(x) = a_kx^k + a_{k-1} x^{k-1} + \dots + a_0.$$

You want that for $n$ pairs $(x_i, y_i)$, the polynomial satisfies $P(x_i) = y_i$, for $1\le i\le n$.

Putting this together, this will give you $n$ equations for the $k+1$ unknown coefficients $a_j$. This *linear system* will (usually) have a unique solution when $n=k+1$ (look up: systems of linear equations). If $n<k+1$, the system is under-determined, and there will usually be more than one polynomial that satisfies the $n$ equations, and if $n>k+1$, often there will not be a solution at all (i.e. there won't be a polynomial of degree $k$ that satisfies all equations).

In general there is no shortcut to this, and the linear system needs to be solved. While it is hard work to solve a $10\times 10$ system by hand, computers are very good at it. If you do it by hand, [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) is probably the way to go.

**Alternatives**. Of course there are other ways to achieve polynomial interpolation, as mentioned by @SammyBlack in the comments. Some don't require you to solve linear systems, like the approach above.

Comment: I like this approach.   The polynomials of degree $n$ form an $n+1$ dimensional vector space,  which enables us to approach it thus ly.  If we do it cleverly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that of polynomial interpolation. Possibly the easiest way to proceed, in this particular case, is via the method of differences. See [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences).

Constructing our difference table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
n& P(n) & d_1(n) & d_2(n) &d_3(n)&d_4(n) & d_5(n)&d_6(n)&d_7(n)&d_8(n)&d_9(n)&d_{10}(n)\\ \hline
\color{blue}{-1} & \color{blue}{1556 } &\color{blue}{-1383 } &\color{blue}{ 1212} & \color{blue}{ -1040} &\color{blue}{869 } &\color{blue}{-700}&\color{blue}{ 535} & \color{blue}{ -378}& \color{blue}{236 }& \color{blue}{ -119}
& \color{blue}{38} \\ \hline
\color{blue}{0} &  \color{blue}{173}&\color{blue}{-171} &\color{blue}{172} & \color{blue}{-171}& \color{blue}{169}& \color{blue}{-165}& \color{blue}{157}& \color{blue}{-142}& \color{blue}{117}& \color{blue}{-81}
& \color{blue}{38}\\ \hline
1 & 2& 1& 1&-2&4&-8&15&-25&36&-43&38\\ \hline
2 & 3 & 2&-1&2&-4&7&-10&11&-7&-5\\ \hline
3 & 5 & 1&1&-2&3&-3&1&4&-12\\ \hline
4 & 6 & 2&-1&1&0&-2&5&-8\\ \hline
5 & 8 & 1&0&1&-2&3&-3&\\ \hline
6 & 9 & 1&1&-1&1&0\\ \hline
7 & 10 & 2&0&0&1\\ \hline
8 & 12 & 2&0&1\\ \hline
9 & 14 & 2&1\\ \hline
10 & 16 & 3&\\ \hline
11 & 19 & &\\ \hline
\end{array}$$ where $d_n(x) =d_{n-1}(x+1)-d_{n-1}(x)$ and $d_0(x)=P(x)$. The method of differences theorem states that for a polynomial of degree $n$, the $n$th order of difference of $P(x)$ remains constant, and is equal to $n!\cdot a_0$ where $a_0$ is the leading coefficient of $P(x)$.

Therefore, $P(-1)=1556$.